# Flutter http get failing due to .substring

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, http

Weird one for you today...

```
  var url = Uri.parse(myRedactedUrl);
  try {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 12)); // Timeout active
    print(url.toString().substring(0,70)); // <<<< Problem
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      decoded = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (decoded['status'] == 0) {success = false;}
      if (decoded['status'] == 1) {success = true;}
    } else {success = false;}
  } catch (e) {success = false;}
```

The following http request completely fails if the print line marked '<<< Problem' is included. Anyone have any idea why?

It only occurs when getting a sub string of the 'url', and I can imagine it might be actually altering that variable somehow, but this doesn't seem intuitive and the sequence seems to suggest it shouldn't matter anyway.

I can't see why printing a substring of the url variable should affect the line above. I've tried removing the .substring and the problem disappears.

Comment: Well, the line probably fails with an exception, likely because your substring range is out of bounds (as explained by [the `substring` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/substring.html), both indices must not be greater than `length`). Your code then catches and silently swallows all exceptions (and this is an example of why [doing that is a bad practice](https://dart.dev/effective-dart/usage#dont-explicitly-catch-error-or-types-that-implement-it)).

Comment: You might want to try `print(url.length)` before that line to see the URL actual length. It might be less than 70.

Comment: Print the URL without the substring. Maybe the length is less than 70 characters.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for your responses - I didn't know that about  try/catch and this has been a valuable learning opportunity